# C# textbox cursor positioning

Tags: c#, textbox, text-cursor

I feel like I am just missing a simple property, but can you set the cursor to the end of a line in a textbox?

```
private void txtNumbersOnly_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == '\b' || e.KeyChar == '.' || e.KeyChar == '-')
   {
      TextBox t = (TextBox)sender;
      bool bHandled = false;
      _sCurrentTemp += e.KeyChar;

      if (_sCurrentTemp.Length > 0 && e.KeyChar == '-')
      {
         // '-' only allowed as first char
         bHandled = true;
      }

      if (_sCurrentTemp.StartsWith(Convert.ToString('.')))
      {
         // add '0' in front of decimal point
         t.Text = string.Empty;
         t.Text = '0' + _sCurrentTemp;
         _sCurrentTemp = t.Text; 
         bHandled  = true;
      }

      e.Handled = bHandled;
   }
```

After testing for '.' as first char, the cursor goes before the text that is added. So instead of "0.123", the results are "1230." without moving the cursor myself.

I also apologize if this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
t.SelectionStart = t.Text.Length;
```

Answer (score 3):

in WPF you should use :

```
textBox.Select(textBox.Text.Length,0);
```

where 0 is the number of characters selected

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `SelectionStart` property on the textbox will control the cursor position.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using WinForms and not WPF...

```
void SetToEndOfLine(TextBox tb, int line)
{
   int loc = 0;
   for (int x = 0; x < tb.Lines.Length && tb <= line; x++)
   {
      loc += tb.Lines[x].Length;
   }
   tb.SelectionStart = loc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will usefull.

```
        private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string c = "";
        string d = "0123456789.";
        foreach (char a in textBox.Text)
        {
            if (d.Contains(a))
                c += a;
        }
        textBox.Text = c;
        textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;
    }
```